# Dynamically generating images for OAuth in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create

Images for my OAuth 
make them clickable
here is my code,

I am using pro as a variable to concatenate the images of the OAuth providers

thanks

Ehi

```
@foreach (var provider in loginProviders)
    {
        var pro = "~/images/icons/" + @provider.Name;
        pro = pro + ".gif";
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.Name</button>
                    <img img src=@pro />
```

What I get in return is https://localhost:44335/Accounts/~/images/icons/Facebook.gif

What I expect is https://localhost:44335/images/icons/Facebook.gif

Comment: Try using .../images/icons/ or you may have to use .../.../images/icons/ . I would try the first one mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` character is not actually a supported URL component. ASP.NET has by convention treated that as a path component referring to the document root and in one way or another replaces it dynamically when processing the HTML. Here, that would be Razor's job to resolve that, but that doesn't seem to be happening for some reason. I can't say for sure why with the code you've provided, but as a workaround, you can try wrapping it with `Url.Content`:

```
var pro = Url.Content("~/images/icons/" + @provider.Name);
```

That basically explicitly forces it to be resolved before it's set in the variable.